# Are register of Converters in BeanUtils thread-local?

Tags: java, thread-safety, thread-local, apache-commons-beanutils

I have a web project where `BeanUtils` is used to manipulation beans.

In my code, in order to make `BeanUtils` transfer string records into `java.util.Date` fields properly, a `DateConverter` is registered into `ConvertUtils` class like that:

```
ConvertUtils.register(dateConverter, Date.class);
```

Moreover, In my project, different date formats is needed in different Actions, So, I registered different converters in different actions like that:

```
public void Action1(){
    DateTimeConverter dtConverter = new DateConverter();
    dtConverter.setPatterns(dateFormats1);
    ConvertUtils.register(dtConverter, Date.class);
    ...
    BeanUtils.populate(myBean1, hashMap1);
}
public void Action2(){
    DateTimeConverter dtConverter = new DateConverter();
    dtConverter.setPatterns(dateFormats2);
    ConvertUtils.register(dtConverter, Date.class);
    ...
    BeanUtils.populate(myBean2, hashMap2);
}
```

But later, I noticed that registered Converter with same target class (`Date` here) will replace each other. So if `ConvertUtils.register` operation is not thread local, problems caused by concurrence may happen here, even through my website haven`t met any yet.

So, would converter registered in one thread replace converter registered in another thread? If so, is there any work around for my circumstance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache commons beanutils uses a [ContextClassLoaderLocal](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/ContextClassLoaderLocal.html) to manage the framework's instances. The concept is similar to a `ThreadLocal` except that it binds an instance to a thread's context class loader.

So when the threads that execute `Action1` and `Action2` share the same context class loader a change to the `ConverterUtils` in one action will affect the other.

To be safe you can use an own instance of a `BeanUtilsBean` in each action, e.g.

```
public void Action1(){
    BeanUtilsBean beanUtils = new BeanUtilsBean();
    ConvertUtilsBean convertUtils = beanUtils.getConvertUtils();
    DateTimeConverter dtConverter = new DateConverter();
    dtConverter.setPatterns(dateFormats1);
    convertUtils.register(dtConverter, Date.class);
    ...
    beanUtils.populate(myBean1, hashMap1);
}
```

Of course it would be better to configure the `BeanUtilsBean` once in the constructor of your class and just use it.

Comment: Well, there is still a small problem in the code, line 6 should be `beanUtils .getyConvertUtils().register(...)` to work

Comment: But `convertUtils` is the result of `beanUtils.getConvertUtils()`. Do I miss something here !?